# why is the value being changed even in a const function?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
    {
      int value1; 
      public :
        void fun() const
        {
        ((temp*)this)->value1 = 10;
        }
        void print()
        {
            cout<<value1<<endl;
        }
     };
int main()
{
  temp t;
  t.fun();
  t.print();
}
```

Comment: incidentally a nicer way to do this is to make value1 mutable

Comment: @jk: The big downside of `mutable` is that it makes the variable mutable for *all* methods, not just one. The cast is much less invasive and thus the lesser evil IMHO.

Comment: Advice: Only use C++ style casts ("*_cast") to make your intent visible. Do not use the C-Style casts "(type)", because these are all possible casts rolled into one.

Comment: Are you asking as what the author of this code had on mind or why doesn't the compiler complain and the output is, as it is?

Comment: @Frerich Raabe, yes but `mutable` would express your intent that the variable is mutable beyond normal const rules. Looking at the interface for that class, that's not readily apparent. Oh and I like how `fun` is const but `print` isn't :)

Comment: @Frerich: excellent difference to bring into the discussion, though that does cut both ways.  There's a lot less "digging" to notice mutable where the member's declared - an easy "heads up" - whereas a cast in one particular function could so easily be overlooked, prolonging trouble-shooting.  I use both as I feel fit, which is probably pretty arbitrary at times :-).

Answer (score 14):

Because you're casting away `const`...

When you cast something, the responsibility is yours for making sure that it doesn't do something dumb.

---

Note that if `temp t;` is changed to `const temp t;`, you get undefined behavior, for modifying a `const` value.

Coincidentally I literally just touched on this in [my blog](http://blackninjagames.com/?p=91). (Almost the same function, too.)

Comment: Hey haha i didn't know you have a blog. nice :)

Answer (score 5):

$5.4/5 is about `explicit type conversion` (which is what is being used here)

> The conversions performed by
>
> — a const_cast (5.2.11),
>
> — a static_cast (5.2.9),
>
> — a static_cast followed by a const_cast,
>
> — a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10), or
>
> — a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of
>   explicit type conversion. The same
>   semantic restrictions and behaviors
>   apply. **If a conversion can be
>   interpreted in more than one of the
>   ways listed above, the interpretation
>   that appears first in the list is
>   used, even if a cast resulting from
>   that interpretation is ill-formed.**
>   If a conversion can be interpreted in
>   more than one way as a static_cast
>   followed by a const_cast, the
>   conversion is ill-formed.

In this case, `((temp*)this)` got treated as `(const_cast<temp *>(this))` and was well-formed. This removed away the constness, thereby allowing to change the class member value.

Answer (score 3):

C++ tries to prevent accidental errors, but it doesn't go out of its way to fight a programmer who's determined to have things their own way.  If you use cast operators you're telling it "trust me, I know what's there", demanding it ignore it's own knowledge of the program.  It's precisely because the C-style casting operator you've used is dangerous and can be easily misused that C++ introduces static_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast, which communicate the programmer's intent in such a way that the compiler can still say "hey, hold on there, that'd require more than just the type of leniency you're asking for".  reinterpret_cast is the big daddy though... no arguing with that... just as brutal as the C-cast and rarely needed in a high-level application.  Precisely because it's rarely needed, verbose and easily seen, it draws scrutiny.  Code littered with C-style casts can easily hide bugs.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` would not work here: it can't cast away constness.